# Data.com: How to unit test with DandBCompany data?

Tags: data.com

In an org with Data.com Premium Clean enabled, I have code that refers to the DandBCompany object to lookup relationships (via DandBCompany.DomesticUltimateDunsNumber).  How do I write unit tests for this logic?  DandBCompany is read-only, so how do I populate it with test data?

Comment: Found a related IdeaExchange suggestion, worth a vote:  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000k7ILAAY&sort=2

Answer (score 1):

Some Objects can't be created in unit tests and you need to use the @isTest(seeAllData=true) annotation to access org data.

In [Isolation of Test Data docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_data_access.htm) Salesforce touches on this with:

> There might be some cases where you can’t create certain types of data from your test method because of specific limitations.

I have had to use the @isTest(seeAllData=true) annotation in the past to deal with those situations.  I don't see how you can avoid it.  You can't create the needed record with data in your unit test.